# SPLIT URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have below URL in my code and i want to split it and get the number from it

For example from the below URL  need to fetch 123456

https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/

I have tried this and it is not working

```
$completeURL  = https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/  ; 

  list($url, $number) = explode('#c', preg_replace('/^.*\/+/', '', $completeURL));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

It's specifically made for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without using regex also -

```
$completeURL  = 'https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/'  ; 

list($url, $number) = explode('#c', str_replace('/', '', $completeURL));

echo $number;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to get the */c/123456/* **params** you will need to execute the following:

```
$url = 'https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/';
$url_fragment = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
$fragments = explode('/', $url_fragment);
$fragments = array_filter(array_map('trim', $fragments));
$fragments = array_values($fragments);
```

1. The **PHP_URL_FRAGMENT** will return a **component** of the url after **#**
2. After parse_url you will end up with a **string** like this: '/c/123456/'
3. The `explode('/', $url_fragment);` function will return an array with empty indexes where '/' was extracted
4. In order to remove empty indexes `array_filter($fragments);` the
   array_map with trim option will remove excess spaces. It does not
   apply in this case but in real case scenario you better trim.
5. Now if you var_dump the result you can see that the array needs to
   be reindexed `array_values($fragments)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

basename — Returns trailing name component of path

```
<?php

echo basename("https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/");

?>
```

Demo : http://codepad.org/9Ah83qaP

Answer (score 0):

Subsequently you can directly take from pure regex to fetch numbers from string,

```
preg_match('!\d+!', "https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff3b8045d8705cf7c9baf581198b0a2d6630574b)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$tmp = explode( '/', $completeUrl).end();
```

It will explode the string by '/' and take the last element

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other option than regex, for your example data you could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to split your url instead of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

An approach could be to

- Capture the first part as a group `(.+\/)`
- Then capture your number as a group `(\d+)`
- Followed by a forward slash at the end of the line `\/$/`

This will take the last number from the url followed by a forward slash.

Then you could use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and skip the first item of the `$matches` array because that will contain the text that matched the full pattern.

```
$completeURL  = "https://review-test.com/#/c/123456/";
preg_match('/(.+\/)(\d+)\/$/', $completeURL, $matches);
list(, $url, $number) = $matches;
```